# Make ALL flex-items wrap (like flex-direction: column) when any one flex-item too wide for flex-container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The use case for this is a responsive form with radio buttons. When on a big PC screen, all radio buttons normally fit in one line on the screen (like flex items in a non-wrapping flex container with `flex-direction: row`). On a phone, not all radio buttons normally fit on one line. If any one radio button won't fit, I want them all to display one per line (like flex items in a flex container with `flex-direction: column`).

This would be easy if I knew how long my radio button labels were going to be, but I don't (they come from a client configurable database).
[image]

So what I want is like this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Responsive Radio Button</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      @media (min-width: 652px) {
        .flexContainer {
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: row;
        }
      }
      @media (max-width: 652px) {
        .flexContainer {
          display:flex;
          flex-direction: column;
        }
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='flexContainer'>
      <div>Medium Length div</div>
      <div>Short div</div>
      <div>Longest div in this entire html page!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

where I don't know before hand what the `@media (min-width: /max-width:)` breakpoint is.

### What I tried

#### This is my work in progress code

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Responsive Radio Button</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .flexContainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content:stretch;
        /** border so I can see what is going on */
        border: 1px dotted lightblue;
      }
      .flexItem {
        /** white-space and min-width stop text wrapping */
        white-space: nowrap; 
        min-width: max-content;
        /** next three lines could be shortened to flex: 1 0 0px; (grow shrink basis) */
        flex-basis: 0;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        /** border and margin so I can see what is going on */
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 2px;
      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='flexContainer'>
      <div class='flexItem'>Medium Length div</div>
      <div class='flexItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='flexItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='flexItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='flexItem'>Longest div in this entire html page!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**flex: 1 0 0**
This is used to make all flex items equal in main axis size. But when the wrapping kicks in, the equality of main axis size drops off. If the flex-items all remained the same size, they would all be too long for the parent flex-container at the same time, so would all wrap.
This does NOT happen, though, as the minimum size of each flex-item is different, so although the flex items never shrink, they all start growing to fill the left over space from starting from a different size.

It's like I want a `flex-basis: largest-sibling`, by which I mean the smallest flex-item would start at the same size as the largest flex item, and never get smaller than that largest flex-item.

Comment: Not possible with flexbox or any other layout method. Javascript is required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key insights here are:

1) [This problem is a two dimensional problem](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox).

Two dimension problems: solve with `display: grid;`

One dimension problems: solve with `display: flex;`

I was thinking as this problem as a single dimension problem because I wanted my radio buttons to be in one case horozontal, and in the other case vertical - both refer to a single dimension. I was wrong because it involves a transition between being vertical and being horozontal, so it is a two dimension problem.

### 2) [grid-auto-flow: column](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-columns);

I also had to pick an arbitrary view port width to flick from vertical to horozontal, and use a @media statement.

This answer is not perfect, it does not equally size the options when they are not in one horozontal line, but it achieves what I was looking for:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Responsive Radio Button</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      @media(max-width: 600px) {
        .resize {
          grid-template-columns: 600px;
        }
      }
      @media(min-width: 600px) {
        .resize {
          grid-auto-flow: column;
          grid-auto-columns: 1fr;
        }
      }
      .gridContainer {
        display: grid;

        /** border so I can see what is going on */
        border: 1px dotted lightblue;
      }
      .gridItem {
        /** white-space and min-width stop text wrapping **/
        white-space: nowrap; 
        min-width: max-content;
        /** border and margin so I can see what is going on */
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 2px;

      }
      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='gridContainer resize'>
      <div class='gridItem'>Medium Length div</div>
      <div class='gridItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='gridItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='gridItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='gridItem'>Longest div in this entire html page!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If you are willing to use `@media` then I think flex is better for you as you can just change `flex-direction` and everything should work.  With `gap-row` and `gap-column` now fairly widely supported, I think this is a great use of flex rather than grid.

Like you though, I was really hoping to avoid media queries and would love a way to tell Flex "if you can fit it all in a row, then do `flex-direction: row` otherwise do `flex-direction: column`.

Answer (score 0):

This is what i've made from your coded. See if it helps you

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Responsive Radio Button</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      .flexContainer {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content:stretch;
        /** border so I can see what is going on */
        border: 1px dotted lightblue;
      }
      .flexItem {
        /** white-space and min-width stop text wrapping */
        white-space: nowrap; 
        min-width: max-content;
        /** next three lines could be shortened to flex: 1 0 0px; (grow shrink basis) */
        flex-basis: 0;
        flex-grow: 1;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        /** border and margin so I can see what is going on */
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: 2px;
      }
      @media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
        .flexContainer {
          flex-flow: column;
        }
      }

      </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='flexContainer'>
      <div class='flexItem'>Medium Length div</div>
      <div class='flexItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='flexItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='flexItem'>Short div</div>
      <div class='flexItem'>Longest div in this entire html page!</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the CSS grid can achieve the closest answer to your needs

```css
.flexContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(600px,1fr))
}
```

```html
<div class='flexContainer'>
      <div>Medium Length div</div>
      <div>Short div</div>
      <div>Longest div in this entire html page!</div>
  </div>
```

[Auto sizing columns in CSS grid](https://css-tricks.com/auto-sizing-columns-css-grid-auto-fill-vs-auto-fit/)

You can read more about it here and tweak it to fit your needs

Comment: Thanks m_sultan - you made me re-read the doco on grid vs flex and as https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Relationship_of_Grid_Layout says, grid is for two dimensions and flex is for one dimension. Even though I am only in one row or one column, my problem is in two dimensions. I am trying your suggestion now but it does not force them all onto the same single row - they spill to a 2nd row but maintain a consistent size (which is an improvement) - will keep trying